# How can we use InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope in Autofac configuration Json/XML file

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

How can I register the scope as InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope in  configuration (Json/Xml) as provided by the Autofac. As of now it is throwing my exception as Invalid Scope.

Answer (score 1):

Autofac configuration does not currently support instance per matching lifetime scope. [You can see the code here where lifetime scope values are parsed](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Configuration/blob/e1cf62b26e2177f975253496e8bf671ec9b09c2c/src/Autofac.Configuration/Core/ComponentRegistrar.cs#L504) and there is a [table in the documentation showing what is currently supported](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/xml.html#components) - be sure to scroll to the right in the table so you can see the list of valid values.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this solution.

Make sure you used proper string in the configuration, try below

```
{
  "instanceScope": "per-matching-lifetime" 
}
```

I guess you could do it by creating a Custom Module

```
 public class CustomModule : Module
 {
    public bool TagName { get; set; }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.Register<CustomType>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(TagName);
    }
 }
```

Configuration:

```
 {
    "modules": [{
        "type": "MyNamespace.CustomModule, MyAssembly",
        "properties": {
           "TagName": "customRequest"
         }
     }]
 }
```

If this does not help, please provide additional details about project type(asp.net core/asp.net mvc), exception details, and stack trace.